# Easiest way to extract e-mail from the body of thousands of e-mail addresses?

Tags: email, extract

Long story short, I lost my contacts from an old e-mail but I have their e-mail/details in the body of invoices that I forwarded to my current address. I've been copying thousands of e-mail out out by hand, but am realizing I'll have carpal tunnel before it's done. Is there a way to do this short of hiring someone to write a script? Tried forwarding e-mail to Thunderbird, but the extension that looked like it might do this doesn't search the body of e-mail https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/email-address-crawler/

Also, looking into autohotkey, but am under time constraints. Grateful for any pointers here!

Comment: Can you post part of the body so we can see how they are separated (ie, comma separated), the format and if we can help? Dont forget to change the emails before posting